# Method with same name and signature but different return type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, inheritance, polymorphism

I had an interview where I was asked the following:

Question: A method with same name and signature but different return type. Is it possible and what is this type called he asked me.

Can someone please tell me the following:

1. Is above thing possible in any scenarios (Like one in base class and one in derived class atleast ?) If so what type is it ? Like compile or runtime polymorphism ?
2. In compile time polymorphism, what if the return types of methods are also different along with signature ? But only the name of function is same. Is it compile time polymorphism still ?
3. In overriding, what if I have different return type but the method name and signature are same ? Is it possible ? (He asked me this question, I answered wronglY :() Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What was _your_ answer, and why?

Comment: It is not possible. You can try to overload your methods in that kind of way, but the compiler will not accept that.

Comment: @Oded: lol I just realized I answered incorrectly. I said, its called compiletime polymorphism and within same class its not possible, but one virtual function can be in base class and we can override it or use "new" keyword in derived class with different return type. But if we have it in same class, it will give an error saying, two functions have same name. I wasn't thoughtful and careful during interview, I just realized :( lol this simple question I couldn't answer, gone. I should work on this more.

Comment: @Nolonar: Thank you so much for your answer, I will work this all possible scenarios in VS tonight to understand this well... Thank you so much again :) Cheers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I assume the question is about [return type covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

It allows a method to return a more-derived type than the one declared in a base type e.g.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    object GetValue();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public string GetValue() { return "Hello world"; }
}
```

This is supported in Java but not in C#. The above will not compile since the return type of `SomeClass.GetValue` is `string` not `object`.

Note that you cannot overload methods based on return-type alone i.e. the following is not valid:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int GetValue() { return 1; }
    public string GetValue() { return "abc"; }
}
```

You could do something similar using interfaces although you would need to implement them explicitly to disambiguate:

```
public interface IValue<T> { T GetValue(); }
public class SomeClass : IValue<int>, IValue<string>
{
    string IValue<string>.GetValue() { return "abc"; }
    int IValue<int>.GetValue() { return 1; }
}
```

If the names are the same but the parameters are different then this is method overloading. This is a form of polymorphism (ad-hoc polymorphism). Overloads are resolved statically at compile-type (unless you're using `dynamic` in which case they are deferred to run-time).

You can overload on both the number of parameters and their type, so the following are all valid:

```
public void DoSomething(int value) { }
public void DoSomething(string value) { }
public void DoSomething(int value, string value) { }
```

Note that you can vary the return type of these methods - methods cannot only be overloaded based on their return type alone but they can differ if their parameter lists are different.

Again this is return type covariance and is not supported in C#.

Comment: thank you, but in 2nd question, I am curious to know, when we say a method is overloading. Like, we should have the same name for the method first ? Second,we should vary the param by numbers or type ? And finally I should have same return type right ?Else the program will not compile at all, is that what you mean ? And no concept in C# is there in this right ?

Comment: @Divine - When overloading the method names must be the same, but the parameter lists must be different. They can differ in the types and/or the number of parameters. The don't need to have the same return type, it's just that overload resolution is done only on the parameters of a method, not the return type. This means methods cannot be overloaded on their return type alone. I've updated the answer with this information. C# does allow method overloading, but does not allow methods to be overloaded based on return type, and does not allow return-type covariance.

Comment: Thank you so much, as Todd said, public int DoSomething(string value) { }
public void DoSomething(int value, string value) { } I can have this right ? No problem ? However I understand its not overloading

Answer (score 13):

In C#, you cannot have methods like

`int Foo() { return 1; }`

`void Foo() { return; }`

They must vary by more than return type.

If the arguments are different, then you're good to go.

`int Foo(string x) { return 1; }`

`void Foo(double x) { return; }`

Comment: That perfectly make me understand, thank you so much :) Cheers

Comment: BTW, I don't see polymorphism here at all, but I didn't sit in your interview. :) Real quick, polymorphism would be like void Foo(Animal a){..} and class Dog : Animal{}. You make the call Foo(aDog) with a Dog not an Animal. Polymorphism does the magic conversion from your derived type (Dog) to the base type (Animal). More info on polymorphsism here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4839/Building-Snap-In-Applications

Comment: Thank you again Todd, somehow lot of things appear new to me as I didn't have touch for 3 months now. Again I am a beginner (Around 2 years experience I have, a lot to learn still)... thank you :) I am going through this codeproject link :) Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Though return type covariance is not supported in C#, it is possible to emulate it by using explicit implementation and method hiding. That is a pattern which is used thoroughly in the ADO.NET APIs.

E.g.:

```
public interface ISomeValue { }
public abstract class SomeValueBase : ISomeValue { }
public class SomeValueImpl : SomeValueBase { }

public interface ISomeObject { ISomeValue GetValue(); }

public abstract class SomeObjectBase : ISomeObject
{
    ISomeValue ISomeObject.GetValue() { return GetValue(); }
    public SomeValueBase GetValue() { return GetValueImpl(); }

    protected abstract SomeValueBase GetValueImpl();
}

public class SomeObjectImpl : SomeObjectBase
{
    protected override SomeValueBase GetValueImpl() { return GetValue(); }
    public new SomeValueImpl GetValue() { return null; }
}
```

By doing that, the net result of calling `GetValue()` is that it will always match the most specific available type.

Comment: Thank you Jean for explaining me, it helps me :) Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple methods with the same signature but different return types, using Explicit Interface Implementation as shown here:

```
public interface I {
  int foo();
}

public class C : I {
  double foo() { return 2.0; }
  int I.foo() { return 4; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an interview question, you can run with your answer a bit.

Strictly speaking, a method with different return type and the same signature is not possible.  However, broadly speaking, there are many ways of implementing a method whose concrete run time return type varies.

One is using generic parameters.  Another is returning an interface or a super class with multiple implementations.  Or, you can return an object, which can be cast to anything.

As many mentioned, you can also use the "new" keyword to return a derived type of the same method in a subclass.

Comment: Thank you gabnaim for the answer, that helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the same method, same parameters (need to customize) and different return values.

Just follow the codes below, it might help you.

```
public class myClass
{
    public int myReturn() { return 123; }
    public string myReturn(string temp = null) { return "test"; }
}
```

the thing is, it requires parameter to make execute the functions, but you still able to ignore the parameters since you have `string temp = null` as optional parameters, which is you still call the functions with or without the parameters.

Comment: I don't think so, it won't compile with "var x = myReturn();"

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this exact issue since I was parsing a config file with various types that all use a standard sort of config.Parse(string settingName) type interface.

1st Solution Generic Method:

```
T Parse<T> (string settingName)
{
    T Result;
    doParsing...
    return T;
}
```

I didn't really like this since it involved explicitly specifying the type that's being used such as `someSetting = Parse<float>("param");`

So the solution I used is redundant but much more clean in my opinion:

```
T Parse<T> (string settingName, out T result)
{
    doParsing...
    return T;
}
```

The out variable and the return are identical so it's a bit redundant but it enables what I think is a much cleaner interface:

```
setting = Parse("intparam", out setting);
```

And you get methods that vary only by return type for a slight cost of redundancy. On top of that if the type of your data changes, for instance from a double to a float, then you everything will continue working just fine, whereas with the first solution you'd end up getting cannot implicitly convert errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dynamic` return type:

- [dynamic (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)
- [Using Type dynamic (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it whit interface

```
   public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Metoda1()enter code here`;
}
public class MyClass : test.IMyInterface
{
    public IMyInterface Metoda1()
    {
        return new MyClas();
    }
    int test.IMyInterface.Metoda1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        IMyInterface inst = instance.Metoda1();
     /*   IMyInterface ints2 = inst.Metoda1(); //will not compile*/
        Console.WriteLine(inst.GetType().ToString()); ;
        object inst3 = inst.Metoda1();
        Console.WriteLine(inst3.GetType().ToString());
    }
```