# Overloading functions by return type in C#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, explicit

I am currently studying C#, and someone told me that can you can actually overload a methods return type using the explicit keyword, but he never explained how. I google all over the place , and read some questions and answers on stackoverflow as well, but nowhere did I find such a thing , moreover, in most cases the people that answered said that it is not possible to overload methods by return type. After all this I am beginning to think that there is no such possibility.  Does anybody actually now how can you overload a method return type by using the explicit keyword or is it even possible ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think he was not talking about overloading a method, but overloading an operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx

Comment: Is this what are you looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362424/method-with-same-name-and-signature-but-return-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: He might also mean explicit-interface-implementation which allows multiple methods differing only by return type. However, that's not overloading in strict sense. That's "overloading" in misused common words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't **oveload** by return type. However, you can **define** multiple methods that differ only by the return type. That's two different things, often mistaken.

The `explicit` keyword relates only to operators. I think that's not what he meant, and one of you might also misuse/mishear the actual term.

He might mean `explicit interface implementation` instead.

That's the only (well, maybe except for conversion operators, but they are somewhat special methods) that allows to define many **normal methods** that differ only by return type. The most common is the `GetEnumerator` that is irritatingly required both by `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>, IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator() { return null; }

    // IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return null; } // IMPOSSIBLE

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return null; }
}
```

Note how class Foo defines GetEnumerator that returns a generic iterator. Normally, it's not possible to define now another GetEnumerator that will satisfy the classic IEnumeratble.

However, with the last line, with explicit interface implementation, it is possible. Note how the method name was prefixed with interface name.

Also, be careful: all explicit implementations are PRIVATE, that's why there's no access specifier on it. This means, that despite successfully defining them, you will not be able to overload upon that. The explicit one will always be hidden and never used, unless you cast the Foo up to plain IEnumerable.

So:

```
Foo foo = ...; // 
foo.GetEnumerator();   // calls normal typed GetEnumerator<>
((IEnumerable)foo).GetEnumerator();   // calls untyped GetEnumerator
```

word of warning: the rule is held ALSO in the class' body, what can be very misleading sometimes:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>, IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator() { return null; }

    private void test()
    {
        // relatively obvious:

        this.GetEnumerator(); // calls GetEnumerator<>() !
        ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator(); // calls plain GetEnumerator()
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // very inobvious:

        return this.GetEnumerator(); // calls GetEnumerator<> ! no recursion!!

        // ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator(); // would call itself recursively
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. I would vote up but I can't. I will ask this person later if he really ment overloading a operator rather then a method, probably he either used the wrong word or deliberately caused me a headache.

Comment: **However, you can define multiple methods that differ only by the return type**  --- really? the code doesn't compile:         `static string F(int x)
        {
            return "";
        }

        static int F(int y)
        {
            return 0;
        }`

Comment: @LeiYang: You've missed a whole lot of my post. The code you provide in your comment is an attempt to create an overload that differs by return type. Have you seen the code example I provided? `public class Foo` and so on? Look carefully what's inside that class. There is even a comment that marks **the overload** you cannot do, and there are two **GetEnumerator** methods **defined**, and those methods have the same name, same arguments, and differ by return type, and those two methods are NOT overloads.

Comment: hi, i didn't mean to affend you, but i'm expecting the sentence itself to be always correct without other context, because you have so many scores.

Comment: @LeiYang: `expecting the sentence itself to be always correct without other context` - ok, I see how that may be misleading if not reading whole text of the answer. I'll think about it and try to improve wording there. (although human communication is mostly all about the context :) but I see your point :) )

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you ca overload on return types. the return type is not included in the method signature. the compiler determines the overload before it checks whether the return value will cause an error in a larger context (this is if you actually use the return value).

what would happen if you're not using the return value. the compiler will have no idea what overload to use. one such example is below.

```
string func(int i){return "";}
int func(int i){return 0;}

void main(){
    func(1);//what happens here??? which method gets called??
}
```