# Cannot hide inherited member compiler error

Tags: c#, abstract-methods, method-hiding

I'm tring to do :

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Task Execute(); 
}

public abstract class Concrete<T> : Base where T : class
{
    new public abstract Task<T> Execute();
}
```

But for some reason I am getting the compiler error :

> CS0533 'Concrete.Execute()' hides inherited abstract member 'Program.Base.Execute()

I've hidden plenty of members in the past but never met this side case and I'm quite puzzled here. Spent a long time on MSDN and the web but couldn't find anything about this behaviour.

I would really appreciate any insight on the issue.

Here's [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELjZB6).

Comment: Even though it's lacking a `virtual`, `override` worked for me in place of `new`. However, there is still the issue that you're changing the return type when you're hiding the base value. You'll need to change the name or make the subclass return a value of `Task`.

Comment: @mason I assumed the compiler would pick up the definition on Concrete<T> (I've seen that the return type is correctly infered by IntelliSense when I do that - despite the compiler error). So if I understand you correctly the issue is that it is not possible to change the signature when hiding with `new` ? (I have a sense that I did it in the past,  I might be wrong though)

Comment: @mason here's a counter example, the signature can be changed with properties : https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4IkHj it seems that the issue is related to methods / abstract members somehow

Comment: @Max Thanks for your help but please see my comment to mason, the signature should not need to be the same with `new` and the `new` keywords is supposed to work on both methods and properties - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Comment: Possibly relevant (duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/15362589/56778. Note in particular that the C# language does not allow overloaded methods to differ by return type only.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks a lot for your help, unfortunately this is not a covariance situation I'm afraid, I've just browsed the question but it doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the base method is `abstract`. A class inheriting from `Concrete<T>` would *have to* override `Base.Execute()`, but it *could not* override it, because it is hidden by `Derived<T>.Execute()`. So, `Concrete<T>` would be an `abstract` class that can't possibly have any implementation (at least not in C#), at thus it would be useless. So, the C# compiler does not let you write it.

If `Base` was an interface, you could work around this by using an explicit interface implementation. But there is nothing like explicit base class implementation, so I don't think there is any way to have this kind of code, at least not without renaming one of the two methods.

Comment: I just realized it and came back to this tab to say it - but you said it much better than I would have. I was thinking that : if someone references a `Concrete` variable as a `Base` type the abstract member would be undefined. Thanks very much.

Comment: There is no such thing as "undefined" in C#, because luckily, C# is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN :

> An abstract method declaration introduces a new virtual method but
>   does not provide an implementation of that method. Instead,
>   non-abstract derived classes are required to provide their own
>   implementation by overriding that method

Well, the reason for this error is how abstractions work in C#, abstraction can be inherited, it can be implemented but it cannot be hidden or replaced by another abstraction.

Besides, consider the code :

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract Task Execute();
    public abstract Task<int> Execute();
}
```

This will not compile, because :

> Type 'Base' already defines a member called 'Execute' with the same
>   parameter types

So why should it work when we move the second method to a derived abstract class ?

Comment: This class: `public class Base
{
    public Task Execute() => null;
    public Task<int> Execute() => null;
}` does not compile with the same error as your `Base`. But these two classes do: `public class Base
{
    public Task Execute() => null;
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new Task<int> Execute() => null;
}`. So that part of your reasoning is not correct: such error can be fixed by moving the method to a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already explained why this error is given.

Here is how to avoid receiving the error:

```
public abstract class RawAbstract
{
    public Task Execute() => RawExecute(); 
    protected abstract Task RawExecute();
}

public abstract class GenericAbstract<T> : RawAbstract where T : class 
{
    protected override Task RawExecute() => Execute();
    new public abstract Task<T> Execute();
}

public abstract class GenericConcrete<T> : GenericAbstract<T> where T : class 
{
    public override Task<T> Execute() { ... }
}
```