# How to implement hidden abstract method?

Tags: c#, class, overriding, abstract, concrete-inheritance

If the abstract method was hidden by previous abstract inheritance, how can I implement it in concrete class? I have no way to access it, only the access to the inheriting abstract method with same name. The system reports error even it's masked. Here is an example:

```
abstract class MyAbClass1
{
  abstract public int MyMethod(int x);
}
abstract class MyAbClass2 : MyAbClass1
{
  abstract public int MyMethod(int x);
}
class Myderived : MyAbClass2
{
  override public int MyMethod(int x)
  {
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Including actual class definitions to illustrate the problem would help. Let the people at home play along.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "previous abstract inheritance" or "masked". Those aren't commonly-used terms. As Jeroen says, code which demonstrates your issue will go a long way towards getting an answer

Comment: Code shown in the post does not compile ([CS0533](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0533) ) since it is not legal in C# to hide abstract method... Please [edit] the question to actually demonstrate what you mean "abstract method was hidden by previous abstract inheritance".

Comment: Probably should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375263/cannot-hide-inherited-member-compiler-error which clarifies that such code is impossible to write...

Answer (score 1):

If `MyAbClass2` does not have an implementation of `MyMethod` it should not even specify it - it remain `abstract`. If it does, then it should use the `override` keyword, whereby `Myderived` can also override.

```
abstract class MyAbClass1
{
  abstract public int MyMethod(int x);
}
abstract class MyAbClass2 : MyAbClass1
{
  // no implementation of MyMethod
}
class Myderived : MyAbClass2
{
  override public int MyMethod(int x) // this now works
  {
    return x;
  }
}
```

or

```
abstract class MyAbClass1
{
  abstract public int MyMethod(int x);
}
class MyAbClass2 : MyAbClass1 // no longer abstract
{
  override public int MyMethod(int x) 
  {
    return x*2;
  }
}
class Myderived : MyAbClass2
{
  override public int MyMethod(int x) // this now works
  {
    return x; // or perhaps base.MyMethod(x) - 42;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess in second case, the method implementation of MyAbClass2 won't be seen in instance of Myderived?

Comment: @oversea: that would be `base.MyMethod`.

Comment: @oversea as Jeroen says you can always access the base implementation, see my update too.