# Having both IEnumerator Start() and void Start() in a single script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sample program from Unity's documentation pages that contains an `IEnumerator Start()` as seen below, but I wonder how I can also have a normal `void Start()` in the same script?

I tried adding the `void Start()` as well, but it threw an error. Then, I tried including my code (which is just writing to console the application's data path) in an `IEnumerator` function though executing it immediately by using `0f` for delay parameter, but it would not print out anything...

What am I missing? What is the usual solution to such a situation where you have to have an `IEnumerator Start()` but you also need to execute starting code?

```
/// Saves screenshots as PNG files.
public class PNGers : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Take a shot immediately.
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return UploadPNG();
        yield return ConsoleMSG();
    }

    IEnumerator UploadPNG()
    {
        // We should only read the screen buffer after frame rendering is complete.
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, with RGB24 format.
        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        // Read the screen contents into the texture.
        tex.ReadPixels( new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0 );
        tex.Apply();

        // Encode the texture into PNG format.
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.Destroy(tex);

        // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder:
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../SavedScreen.png", bytes);

    }

    IEnumerator ConsoleMSG()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
        Debug.Log(Application.dataPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a sample program from Unity's documentation pages that contains
>   an IEnumerator Start() as seen below, but I wonder how I can also have
>   a normal void Start() in the same script?

You **can't**.

This is because you can't have two functions with the-same name. Exception is when the functions have different parameter types. I understand that one `Start` function is a `void` return type while the other one is an `IEnumerator` return type. That doesn't matter in C#. What matters is the parameter of both functions.

In this case, they both **don't** take any argument so you **can't** overload them.You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362424/method-with-same-name-and-signature-but-return-type-in-c-sharp).

Even if you make the `void Start` function take a parameter and the `IEnumerator Start` function not take a parameter, it won't work. For example,

```
void Start(int i)
{
    Debug.Log("Hello Log 1");
}
```

and

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return null;
    Debug.Log("Hello Log 2");
}
```

Unity will throw both compile(Editor) and run-time exception:

> `Script error (<ScriptName>): Start() can not take parameters.`

---

If you switch it around and make the `void Start` not have any parameter but `IEnumerator`  with a parameter, it **will compile** and you **won't** get any error but the `IEnumerator Start` function won't be called when you run/play your game.

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello Log 1");
}
```

and

```
IEnumerator Start(int i)
{
    yield return null;
    Debug.Log("Hello Log 2");
}
```

---

> What is the usual solution to such a situation where you have to have
>   an IEnumerator Start() but you also need to execute starting code?

Run your starting code in in the `IEnumerator Start` function before any other code.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    //Run your Starting code
    startingCode();

    //Run Other coroutine functions
    yield return UploadPNG();
    yield return ConsoleMSG();
}

IEnumerator UploadPNG()
{

}

IEnumerator ConsoleMSG()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
}

void startingCode()
{
    //Yourstarting code
}
```

---

You can also execute the starting code in the `void Awake()` or `void Enable()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed and informative answer.