# Generic class: conditional method based on type

Tags: c#, generics

I have an existing C# generic class and wish to add or remove a method based on the used type, I explain

```
public class MyType<T>
{
    public T getValue() { return value; }
}
```

For the specific `MyType<void>`, I wish to "delete" the "getValue" method.
Does something like this exists?

Comment: Do you mean that for a specific type T, for example string, you want getValue to not exist?

Comment: Yes, by example. I need this method for int, float, bool but not for void !

Comment: What do you mean by add or delete ? Does not matter if you have a generic class or not, you define class methods and those methods will be available, generics basically allow methods to work with different types

Comment: That is not possible; C# does not support explicit specialization; that is, a custom implementation of a template for a specific type.

Comment: Where does `value` come from in the first place? `void` is not a type so you can't construct a `MyType<void>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope but you can probably accomplish something similar with interfaces

```
interface IMyType
{
   //...what ever method/properties are shared for all
}

public class MyType<T> : IMyType
{
   public T getValue() { return value; }
   //...shared methods
}

public class MyTypeOtherSide : IMyType
{
   //...shared methods
}
```

you'd then need to declare the variables as IMyType and only use `MyType<T>` when you know that it is of that type

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using generics is to have a generic type-declaration that works for all types, not just a few ones.

I suppose you want an operation only for *numbers*. You could add a generic constraint on your class as follows:

```
public class MyType<T> where T: struct
{
    public T getValue() { return value; }
}
```

However this will also allow types which have the generic argument `void` to have the `GetValue`-method, as `void` is also a `struct`. However this won´t hurt as you can´t construct a type `MyType<void>` as Lee also mentioned.

Furthermore there´s no common interface that all numeric types implement and that can be used as generic constraint. The only workaround is to have a method for every type, so GetDouble, GetInt, and so on

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I also used this trick (from Lee) to handle everything :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362424/method-with-same-name-and-signature-but-return-type-in-c-sharp